# R returning new columns instead of new rows for additional records

Tags: r, screen-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to find an easy way to take the output and outputs like the one below and convert them to have another row for every additional product column but with the same link in the first column, the ideal output is a data frame that has three columns, first one being the link, one for the product and one for the price.

[I'm scraping this data from a website for practice, but having an issue with my output, right now its returning multiple columns per link where there are multiple products for each link - instead I want unique rows for every product.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRjdA.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: from the R-Tag Info `"R is a free, open-source programming language and software environment for statistical computing, bioinformatics, visualization and general computing. Provide minimal, reproducible, representative example(s) with your questions. Use dput() for data and specify all non-base packages with library calls. Do not embed pictures for data or code, use indented code blocks. For statistics questions, use http://stats.stackexchange.com."`